# Unexpected ',' in Ruby

Tags: ruby, syntax-error

I'm getting a `syntax error, 'unexpected ','` in a Ruby program. Both the ruby intepreter and the Ruby IDE (Eclipse DLTK) indicate an error on the same place, yet it looks perfectly fine to me.

```
main.rb:156: syntax error, unexpected ','

    def create_account(atts={}, entity, server_app)
                                      ^ (SyntaxError)
```

If I comment out or delete the offending line (and the rest of the method), the syntax error moves to the next 3-parameter method definition (no params, 1 or 2-param methods  are not affected)

I'm running Jruby 1.6.7

I guess this has to do with something totally unrelated so I'm looking for some hints/heuristics on what to look for.

---- edit ----

Further experimenting shows that it relates to the use of the inline initialization of the hash:

```
def dummy_two_param_method(dummy={})        #OK
end

def dummy_two_param_method(dummy, damn)     #OK
end

def dummy_two_param_method(dummy={}, damn)  #Syntax error at ')'
end

def dummy_three_param_method(dummy={}, damn, dum_b)
end
```

Comment: Can you post some of the other three parameter functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using default values with ruby 1.8 (jruby 1.6.7 is not completely 1.9 compliant) the default value must be declared last in your method line.

Try `create_account(entity, server_app, atts={})`

Comment: More precisely, all optional parameters must go after all required parameters.

Comment: Looks like my jruby version had an underlying ruby 1.8.x